# Different markers for adjacent levels in nested list

Tags: feature-request, design

I don't know about everyone else, but the styling of nested lists has bothered me for a long time, so I would like to make this an official [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): Please use different markers for adjacent levels in nested unordered lists.

At the moment it just looks like something went wrong and it is hard to follow just the main points without stumbling over the sublist, also marked with ●

[image]　　　　　
[image]

<sub>(taken from [Resources for learning Japanese](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/756/resources-for-learning-japanese))</sub>

The second image makes it much clearer that the list marked by ○ is a sublist and can be skipped on a first reading. (Using different markers for nested unordered lists is also the default style in LibreOffice Writer, Microsoft Word, Evernote, etc.)

I believe this can be implemented by adding

```
ul , ul > li > ul > li > ul , ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  list-style-type:disc;
}

ul > li > ul , ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > ul {
  list-style-type:circle;
}
```

to the style sheet, allowing up to five levels of unordered nested lists (and marking higher nesting with ●), like ● ○ ● ○ ● ● ● … (that's overkill of course, but never mind).

If unordered lists are nested together with ordered lists, I think it is best to default to the ● marker and only use ○ for a marker in a `ul` *inside another* `ul`. (As in 1. ● 1. ● ○ 1. 1. ● etc.) This is achieved by the above code.